# Interface combinations implementation without firmware update wireless linux networking

Tags: linux, wifi, interface, p2p, hostapd

I am working with the Qualcomm WiGig (60GHz) chipsets supported by the Linux networking wil6210 driver. I use Linux kernel 4.12.

In my use case, I would like to use concurrent usage of the WiGig interface. That means one interface is P2P-GO/P2P-Client and another interface is STA/AP. So I can communicate parallel inside a P2P Group and in a PBSS. But checking "iw phy" output of the WiGig interface, it is said that "interface combinations are not supported". Anyway, I tried setting up the supplicant conf file with "driver_param=use_p2p_group_interface=1", and of course it does not work.

I would like to know: Could this concurrent option be added in the driver without any hardware update?

I read in "Multiple Interfaces FAQ" of this link: http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/carl9170/#Multiple_Interfaces_FAQ, that is needed to define multiple interface instances in the firmware. But since I do not have access to edit the firmware. Is there any alternative to implement this concurrent interface?

I appreciate any suggestion,

Thanks, Fernando